# how do i implement android mapbox android sdk successfully in fragment

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using mapbox in a fragment with bottom navigation, when i exit and resume the app or when i change tabs rapidly, the app crashes. this is the error i get

`10-07 22:20:36.046 21867-21886/com.dropexpress.driver.dropexpressdriver E/Mbgl-FileSource: Failed to read the storage key: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource.getCachePath(FileSource.java:88)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource$FileDirsPathsTask.doInBackground(FileSource.java:165)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.storage.FileSource$FileDirsPathsTask.doInBackground(FileSource.java:155)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)`
the below code always fails when i exit the app and resume, or when i change tabs rapidly, i am using bottom navigation.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. here is my fragment code

   ```
   package com.dropexpress.driver.dropexpressdriver.fragments;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.net.Uri;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import com.dropexpress.driver.dropexpressdriver.R;
   import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
   import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
       public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
       private MapView mapView;
       private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
       private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

       private String mParam1;
       private String mParam2;

       private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

       public HomeFragment() {
           // Required empty public constructor
       }

       /**
        * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
        * this fragment using the provided parameters.
        *
        * @param param1 Parameter 1.
        * @param param2 Parameter 2.
        * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
        */
       // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
       public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
           HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
           Bundle args = new Bundle();
           args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
           args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
           fragment.setArguments(args);
           return fragment;
       }

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           if (getArguments() != null) {
               mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
               mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // Inflate the layout for this fragment

           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
           Mapbox.getInstance(requireActivity(), "pk.eyJ1Ijoic3ludGF4bHRkIiwiYSI6ImNqaDJxNnhzbDAwNnMyeHF3dGlqODZsYjcifQ.pcz6BWpzCHeZ6hQg4AH9ww");
           mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
           mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           return  view;
       }

       // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
       public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
           if (mListener != null) {
               mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onAttach(Context context) {
           super.onAttach(context);
           if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
               mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
           } else {
               throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                       + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onDetach() {
           super.onDetach();
           mListener = null;
       }

       /**
        * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
        * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
        * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
        * activity.
        * <p>
        * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
        * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
        * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
        */
       public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
           // TODO: Update argument type and name
           void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
       }
       @Override
       public void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
           mapView.onResume();
       }

       @Override
       public void onPause() {
           super.onPause();
           mapView.onPause();
       }

       @Override
       public void onStop() {
           super.onStop();
           mapView.onStop();
       }

       @Override
       public void onLowMemory() {
           super.onLowMemory();
           mapView.onLowMemory();
       }

       @Override
       public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
           super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
           mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
       }

   }
   ```

**Android versions:** 5.0 +
**Device models:** motorola g5
**Mapbox SDK versions:** 6.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i opened this issue in github, you check their response here

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/13044#issuecomment-427861016

this was their response:

I can see 2 issues with the provided code:

You are not calling `MapView#onDestroy`, this has to be called from you fragment's `#onDestroyView`.
`MapView#onCreate` should be called from fragment's `#onViewCreated`instead of `#onCreateView`.

I applied the changes and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Put your Mapbox.getInstance before inflating your layout.

```
  Mapbox.getInstance(requireActivity(),"Your Map Key");
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
  mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
  mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

I hope this helps you.